# Akka HTTP: How to unmarshal Json format response into domain objects

Tags: json, scala, akka-stream, akka-http, reactive-streams

I am trying out Akka HTTP, and I have created a service that returns a Json Array of domain objects in HttpResponse. In the client I want to convert it to a Source of domain objects so it can be consumed by the subsequent Flows and Sinks.

Referring to the Json Support section:
http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/1.0/scala/http/common/json-support.html

I have done the necessary to define implicit RootJsonReader etc, but I don’t know how to make use of the FromEntityUnmarshaller.

My code is here:
https://github.com/charlesxucheng/akka-http-microservice

It is based on the akka-http-microservice activator template. Service2.scala is my server implementation and is working. AkkaHttpClient.scala is the client implementation and it is incomplete.

To build, pls use Gradle as the build.sbt is not up-to-date.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Akka HTTP now has the ability to do this transparently.

http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/scala/http/common/json-support.html